# Timestamp discontinuity issue in HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: android, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I was trying to do HTTP Live streaming. The segmentation of the files were done using FFMPEG. The segments are of 5 seconds each. In my case every one minute the PCR values of the input "ts" is reset, ie in the segmented files the segments created after every one minute is having a different range of pcr compared to the previous segments(discontinuity in pcr). These segments work fine in apple devices but in android devices the stream gets stuck after one minute. Is there some method to overcome this issue either in the server side or in the android side?

Answer (score 1):

You must set EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY in the m3u8 whenever the PCR value will change:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-14#section-4.3.2.3

Comment: I checked by using the EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag in m3u8 file. But this tag doesn't have any effect on streaming in android.